# Django - Am I in the right direction for creating the models of my travel collaboration application?

Tags: python, django

I am learning Django by building an application, called TravelBuddies. It will allow travelers to plan their trip and keep associated travel items (such as bookings, tickets, copy of passport, insurance information, etc), as well as create alerts for daily activities. The application will also able to update local information such as weather or daily news to the traveler. Travelers can also share the travel information with someone or have someone to collaborate with them to plan for the trip.

So, it will have the following features:

- Main traveler will be able to manage (add, delete and share) trip details and add
  co-traveler (collaborative planning).
- Traveler will be able to login, view and update profile.
- Trip will contain travel schedule and each schedule may have
  associated travel items.
- Any changes made to the schedule will be logged. For collaborative
  planning, each traveler will be notified of the changes.

Here is one of the wireframes of my project:
[image]

I have built the data model of the app. Here are my codes in models.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify


class Coplanner(models.Model):
    coplanner_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.coplanner_name

class Trip(models.Model):
    trip_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    planner_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    add_coplanner = models.ManyToManyField(Coplanner)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, default='null')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.trip_name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.trip_name)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

class Activity(models.Model):
    trip = models.ForeignKey(Trip, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    activity_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    time = models.TimeField(auto_now= True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    item_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    item_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, default='null')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.activity_name

    def save(self):
        super(Activity, self).save()
        self.slug = '%i-%s' % (
            self.id, slugify(self.trip.trip_name)
        )
        super(Activity, self).save()
```

Are my codes correct? Am I in the right direction?

Comment: Are `Coplanner`'s other users within the platform? If so, within the `Trip(models.Model)` the `add_coplaner` should be `models.ManyToManyField(User)` where `User` is imported from [`django.contrib.auth.models`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/), and therefore `Coplanner(models.Model)` is technically not needed.

Comment: You probably want to post this on codereview rather than stack overflow. https://codereview.stackexchange.com